# Firebase + Express + Routes

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm starting with Firebase and trying to implement an api but I'm having trouble trying to create some routes using Express. Follow:

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "/api/**",
      "function": "api"
    },{
      "source": "/api/auth/**",
      "function": "api"
    }]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const api = express();

api.use(cors({ origin: true }))

api.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(api);
```

routes/auth.js

```
var express = require("express");

module.exports = () => {

    var auth = express.Router();

    auth.post("/signin", (request, response) => {
        var service = require("../services/auth/signin");
        service(request, response);
    });

    return auth;

}
```

services/auth/signin.js

```
module.exports = (request, response) => {
    response.status(200).send({
        "success": true,
        "request": request.body.email
    });
}
```

I'm not sure if it's the best framework and if the modules are implemented properly. Any suggestions are very welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

for endpoint to be /api/auth/signin try

```
api.use("/api", require("./routes/auth"));
```

and

```
auth.post("/auth/signin", (request, response) => {
```

then remove

```
,{
  "source": "/api/auth/**",
  "function": "api"
}
```

a little counter intuitive in that it seems to be mapping /api twice, but this is working for me in several apps